# Java RMI just closes and doesn't wait for clients

Tags: java, rmi

This is driving me crazy for hours now.

So here is my main:

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "127.0.0.1");
            ServerInterface server = (ServerInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(new Server(), 0);

            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Configuration.rmiPort);
            registry.bind("server", server);
            System.out.println("Ready");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The Server class contains the logic (at the moment just a method to output some text).

Everytime I compile and run this, the application just closes after "Ready".

I found similiar threads on SO with the same issue, so here is what I tried so far:

- save the registry object in a static field
- using the rmiregistry from outside the program (unmarshalling exception)
- rebind instead of bind
- save the object to be exported in a static field before exporting it

My understanding is that as soon as I export an object to the registry, the thread is kept alive and waiting for connections, no matter if the exported object is only locally declared.

Could this be due to Maven? Because actually I had this code from some YT tutorial and it happened to run on my local machine just fine where I just use `javac` and `java`, but I can't get it to work on the server, where I run the program with `mvn clean install exec:java`.

Comment: "... save the registry object in a static field": that works. What happened when you tried it? Code for that? "My understanding is that as soon as I export an object to the registry, the thread is kept alive and waiting for connections, no matter if the exported object is only locally declared." Your understanding is incorrect. If the references to the remote object and the Regsitry are purely local, they are liable to GC, which will unexport them.